# Recurrence of Merge-Sort - need explanation

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, mergesort, recurrence

This is the recurrence of the worst-case running time T(n) of the Merge-Sort procedure.

What is **T?**

why **2T(n/2) ?**

For which operation is the **O(n)** ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, assume that n is a power of 2 so that each divide step yields two subproblems, both of size exactly n/2.

The base case occurs when n = 1.

When n ≥ 2, time for merge sort steps:

**Divide:** Just compute q as the average of p and r, which takes constant time i.e. Θ(1).

> why 2T(n/2) ?

**Conquer:** Recursively solve 2 subproblems, each of size n/2, which is 2T(n/2).

[image]

> For which operation is the O(n) ?

**Combine:** MERGE on an n-element subarray takes Θ(n) time.

Summed together they give a function that is linear in n, which is Θ(n). Therefore, the recurrence for merge sort running time is

[image]